# Building a REST API: How to decide which params go to Headers, Body, URL or query?

Tags: rest

How do you decide where do parameters go?
Suppose the API is for an object, which has an ID, a few fields and each request may or may not have a token. There has to be GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests for the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, you want all of the parameters necessary to identify a resource to be directly encoded into the URI *somewhere*.  That allows you to bookmark the URI for re-use later, and to share that bookmark with another person/process.

Example:

- [Building a REST API: How to decide which params go to Headers, Body, URL or query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61119398/building-a-rest-api-how-to-decide-which-params-go-to-headers-body-url-or-quer)

All of the context you need to `GET` this resource is right here.  You can click it, save it, send it off in an email, and it is still useful, of itself.

So where in the URI does information go?

If the information is only needed by the client once the representation has been downloaded, then you might consider encoding it into the [fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5).

> The fragment identifier component of a URI allows indirect identification of a secondary resource by reference to a primary resource and additional identifying information.

On the web, fragments were useful because they allowed you to call upon the user agent to focus at a particular element in a representation.  The fragment is not sent over the network, but only used on the client side.  Think [Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) - one big cacheable document (so we don't need a lot of round trips) with lots of URI that point to specific information within it.

Other parameters can be encoded into path segments or the query string.  The machines don't care (20 years ago, this was somewhat less true - we would sometimes have to work around caches that didn't handle the query part of a URI correctly).

URI with parameters configured via `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` query strings were convenient on the web because HTML had form support for creating those identifiers on the client.

These days, we can use [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) to describe how to compute a new URI, which gives you more options.

[Relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) gives us a general purpose mechanism for computing a new URI from a given reference identifier.  Think dot-references with symbolic links.  That mechanism is primarily based on navigating the hierarchical part of the URI, which is to say that [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3).

The machines don't care of the hierarchy of resources and the hierarchy of identifiers are parallel

```
# Here's an identifier for a collection
/collection
# Here's an identifier for a member of this collection
/collection/member

# Here's an identifier for a collection
/2c957fb6-ac92-4fdb-a086-02292c3b7c7c
# Here's an identifier for a member of this collection
/41d36a69-d10c-4503-8e5e-3b2d64e9c3a6
```

All of these samples are *fine*, as far as the machines are concerned; but human beings tend to have an easier time working with the top set.

Headers are metadata that belongs to the domain of "transporting documents over a network".

The body is the document itself - it is the message that is being transported over the network (the http request and the headers are, in a sense, the *envelope* that carries the message).  Yes, this sometimes means that information that is in the message also gets copied into the headers, or copied via the template into the target-uri.

Comment: Amazing example of the GET request!